# ionic2 angularfire2 secuential countdown best way

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-services, angularfire2

I'm using Ionic2, Angularfire 2 and Fireabase 3 on a mobile app.
I use push method that insert records on my data collection and create a unique UID and this is perfect for me. My question is how can I have a sequential number, like beginning on 100 and every time I push(ed) a new record (object), I can take this field add 1, and update that field on the collection. This question is because I like to have like a sequential folio number that user can read easily, because the UID are in a format like: -KgCxt93XTTUWec8Zavb so it will not be easy to say your confirmation number is : -KgCxt93XTTUWec8Zavb, I prefer to say : 101.
Does anybody has done something like this ?
Any ideas will be appreciated.
Reagards,
CaribeSoft.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with `push()`.

You can read more about it [**Work with Lists of Data on the Web**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data).

Another [**article is here**](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

> Use the push() method to append data to a list in multiuser
>   applications. The push() method generates a unique key every time a
>   new child is added to the specified Firebase reference. By using these
>   auto-generated keys for each new element in the list, several clients
>   can add children to the same location at the same time without write
>   conflicts. The unique key generated by push() is based on a timestamp,
>   so list items are automatically ordered chronologically.